# how to use python to execute commands on many servers

Tags: python, concurrency, command

everyone! I have an admin task: I need to write a script to execute commands given in a file on a list of servers whose ip address, login name and password is given in another file. My goal is to execute a command on every server concurrently, that is I don't want to wait until a server finish its command before I ask another server to execute the command. Anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/tutorial.html) could be your answer. I am using it for my current project.