# Executing commands on VMWare using python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, virtual-machine

I have certain shell scripts which I want to execute. These Shell scripts are on various Linux flavours and these Linux will be loaded on Windows 7 using VMWare one by One.

First step would be starting VMWare with Linux image.
This I did by using Command line Params of VMWare

```
from subprocess import call
call(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VMware\\VMware VIX\\vmrun.exe", "start", "< Linux Image Path >" ,"nogui"])
```

Now I want to change the directories and invoke that shell script on this image.
I would need to execute `cd ..../workspace/.....` and `chmod` and then execute shell script.

For this, [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) was perfect tool! But it is not yet ported on Python 3.
I checked with [Invoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/) but couldn't figure out how to do this sort of operation
What should I use and How I should use?

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752613/how-to-use-python-to-execute-commands-on-many-servers) I found on StackOverflow but it was for Python 2

Comment: Why not use `os.system(cmd)`?

Comment: @roymustang86 I also need to get some result files after executing the tests... I would need to implement FTP for that then

Comment: Yeah, if fabric is not an option, then paramiko would be a good option http://www.paramiko.org/

Comment: @roymustang86 FAQ section on the website says "Paramiko doesn’t work with my Cisco, Windows or other non-Unix system" :-(